# What to Store from my model objects in Room Database

Tags: java, android, database, pojo, android-room

I have 3 POJO classes. `Recipe`, `Ingredient` and `Step`.

I want to be able to browse my recipes when offline, so I decided to use `Room`.

**Recipe.class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipe")
public class Recipe implements Parcelable {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
   @SerializedName("id")
   public int recipeId;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "recipe_name")
   public String name;

   @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
   public List<Ingredient> ingredients = null;

   @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
   public List<Step> steps = null;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "recipe_servings")
   public int servings;

   @Ignore
   public String image;

  public Recipe(int recipeId, String name, List<Ingredient> ingredients, List<Step> steps, int servings, String image) {
    this.recipeId = recipeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.steps = steps;
    this.servings = servings;
    this.image = image;
}
...
//getters and setters
...
```

**Converters.class**

```
public class Converters {

    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Ingredient> stringToIngredientList(String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Ingredient>>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String ingredientListToString(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        return gson.toJson(ingredients);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Step> stringToStepList(String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Step>>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String stepListToString(List<Step> steps) {
        return gson.toJson(steps);
    }
}
```

**RecipeDatabase.class**

```
@Database(entities = {Recipe.class}, version = 1)
abstract class RecipeDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static RecipeDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract RecipeDao recipeDao();

    public static RecipeDatabase getRecipeDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RecipeDatabase.class, "recipe-database")
                        // allow queries on the main thread.
                        // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
 }
```

**RecipeDao.class**

```
@Dao
public interface RecipeDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM recipe")
    List<Recipe> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM recipe where recipe_name LIKE  :name")
    Recipe findByName(String name);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from recipe")
    int countRecipes();

    @Update
    void update(Recipe... recipes);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Recipe... recipes);

    @Delete
    void delete(Recipe recipe);
}
```

My question: After saving the `List<Step>` and `List<Ingredient>` as `Strings` using the `Converters` class, should I also save a database of each of my **Step.class** and **Ingredient.class**? Should I include the `@Entity` annotation for these classes too? Should I make a `StepDatabase` and an `IngredientDatabase`? Is that also needed to be able to access my `Recipes` when offline?

Answer (score 1):

> should I also save a database of each of my Step.class and Ingredient.class. Should I make a StepDatabase and an IngredientDatabase?

By all means no. You do not create database per entity, but instead you create a table per entity. In most apps one database is enough.

Traditionally, SQL databases (relational database by nature) should enforce [normalization rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), especially in enterprise systems on servers. Shortly, normalization rules refer to series of refactoring to a relational database design in a manner where each entity is extracted to its own table with foreign keys in the parent table. You'd then have to use SQL SELECT with JOINs to get the data together.

With that said, it's quite common to break the normalization rules for mobile apps and keep the data model as simple as possible by storing the nested entities, in your case, ingredients, and store them as JSON strings or whatever makes sense and easy for you to handle in your code.

So to summarize, what you currently have appear to be really good. As long as it simplifies your code - go for it. As far as I know, Room does not support JOINs, but there's [something pretty close](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded).

There's a good [article on Medium](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) that discusses advanced subjects with Room.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In my opinion it's a good practice to declare a model for each table first and Yes, Every model you should include @Entity annotation telling hibernate that what you are mapping is a table from your db.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Hibernate. The @Entity annotation is refer to Room ORM.